# Network change detection using netlinks not working correctly

Tags: 20.04, network-monitoring, events

I have a netlink socket program to detect if the network connection goes down or when it is back. I m using the cpp program as on [this](https://olegkutkov.me/2018/02/14/monitoring-linux-networking-state-using-netlink/#:%7E:text=The%20Netlink%20is%20a%20socket,to%20the%20Unix%20domain%20sockets.) link, however the results are not very correct.

When I turn the network connection down using the command : `sudo ifconfig <interfaceID> down`, I get the correct output in the RTM_NEWLINK and the condition " `if(ifi->ifi_flags & IFF_RUNNING)`" is getting false.

However, when I turn the network connection up using the command `sudo ifconfig <interfaceID> up`. The same condition gets triggered two times, where in one case it detects networks down and then it detects network up. This is happening everytime the network connection is up and everytime it gets triggered twice first it detects down and then it detects up. Instead it should have detected only up in one trigger.

Is there anything wrong, I m not able to figure out?